# Adding ProfileImage to Photos controller

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, photos

I have the CarrierWave gem installed. There are no galleries, as I have it setup so that photos belong to a user not a gallery.

I added a `avatar` column to the Photos table. The other columns are: id, created_at, updated_at, image, name, user_id

The question is how do I set a action so the users can click 'Make Profile Image' and it will make changes to the `avatar` column? This should be done by either clicking on the thumbnail version of the image or having text overlay.

A example of what I mean:

User Z uploads four photos to their profile. User Z visits their profile and selects one of their uploaded photos to be their Profile image (avatar).

```
   class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def new 
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    @photo.user = current_user
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photos."
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def resize(width, height, gravity = 'Center')
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.combine_options do |cmd|
        cmd.resize "#{width}"
        if img[:width] < img[:height]
          cmd.gravity gravity
          cmd.background "rgba(255,255,255,0.0)"
          cmd.extent "#{width}x#{height}"
        end
      end
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end

  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    if @photo.update_attributes(paramas[:photo])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated photo."
      redirect_to @photo.gallery
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed photo."
    redirect_to @photo.gallery
  end

  def avatar
    @photo = Photo.find params[:photo_id]
    current_user.default_photo = @photo
    redirect_to '/profile'
  end
end
```

view (shows thumb photos on profile):

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)), photo.image_url%>
<% end %></div></p>
```

Comment: I would create a new entity: Photo user_id:int album_id:int for storing all photos from all users, and then allowed each user set any photo as photo in their profile by adding User photo_id:int. Also restricted permission on set photos 'just for fiends'. If you need i can implement it in Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `User` and a `User` has `Photos`, of which one could be the `Avatar`...

What I would recommend you do is have a `avatar_id` on `User`, and a relationship like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  belongs_to :avatar, class_name: 'Photo'
end
```

Then in your `controller`, if you preference is to add a new `action`, it would be like so:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def avatar
    if current_user.update_attribute(:avatar_id, params[:id])
      #set flash success
    else
      #set flash fail
    end
    redirect_to(current_user) # However you plan to handle this...
  end

  ...
end
```

(The reason why you might want to use a new controller is to maintain "DRY")

Which I assume you would have a member `route` like so:

```
resources :photos do
  member do
    post :avatar
  end
end
```

And an `action` like so:

```
button_to('Set as Avatar', [:avatar, @photo])
```

Then you reference it in the view like so:

```
@user.avatar.image_url(:thumb)
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I agree having an avatar_id in the users table is the best choice. But having a line `belongs_to :avatar` in a `User` model makes me sad and reminds me how true the quote "The things you own end up owning you" is... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this so you render the gallery of available photos and allow the user to select one for their DP/Avatar/Profile picture

```
class UserAvatarController < ApplicationController

def edit
@gallery = current_user.gallery
end

def update
if params[:photo_id].present?
  current_user.update_attributes avatar_id: params[:photo_id]
else
  flash[:error] = "No photo selected"
  render action: "edit"
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: To give it a separate controller doesn't seem necessary. Shouldn't I just be able to add a `avatar` column to the Photos table and then assign a action inside the Photos controller that will make the column not NULL for the photo id that was selected? That's the vision that I have but for something so simple I can't seem to compile it.